# Angular carousel, click event inside carousel not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a carousel of cards and using mdb angular for that. Code of the carousel looks something like this in structure:

```html
<mdb-carousel [animation]="'fade'">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let i of test; let j = index">
    <mdb-carousel-item>
      <mdb-card
        class="card text-center"
        (click)="testFunction(j)"
        style="
          width: 15rem;
          margin-top: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          cursor: pointer;
        "
        >{{ i }}
        <div
          class="card-body"
          style="
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
            padding-left: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 1rem !important;
            background-color: ghostwhite;
            font-weight: bold !important;
          "
        ></div>
      </mdb-card>
      <br />
    </mdb-carousel-item>
  </ng-container>
</mdb-carousel>
```

I am calling a function on click event and I am passing id over there. But every time the same id is getting passed over and over, its not working according to *ngFor.
Following is sample the .ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scheduled-events',
  templateUrl: './scheduled-events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scheduled-events.component.scss']
})
export class ScheduledEventsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  test = [1, 2]

  testFunction(i) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Ideally it should print 1 on first slide and 2 on second slide but 2 is getting passed over and over in click event. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks ok. Maybe you should share a full stackblitz example. Maybe you are reusing `i` or `j`. Are there any outer loops in HTML template?

Comment: No other loops, I removed  [animation]="'fade'" from carousel and it was resolved. I did notice two animations happening in carousel fade and slide simultaneously, might be something amiss in material carousel component script. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I removed [animation]="'fade'" from carousel and it started working as expected. Maybe some issue was there with animation script of mdb carousel.